# Remove Signatures From PDF File In Java With Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, digital-signature

I have find problems when i tried to remove signatures from PDF's With Itext 5.1.

This is my Method:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
for (String name : acroFields.getSignatureNames()) {
    acroFields.removeField(name);
}
stamper.close();
output = os.toByteArray();
```

This method works, but not for all PDFs, some PDFs does not find the signatures with this.

Then i found objects on the PDF that flaged SIG, so i created a new method to complement the signature cleanup method:

```
private void removeSignatureObjects(PdfReader reader) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
        PdfObject object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
        if (object != null) {
            if (object.isDictionary()) {
                PdfDictionary dict = (PdfDictionary) object;
                if (validateObjectSign(dict)) {
                    dict.clear();
                    reader.resetReleasePage();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean validateObjectSign(PdfDictionary dict) {
    return PdfName.SIG.equals(dict.get(PdfName.TYPE))
            ||
            (PdfName.ANNOT.equals(dict.get(PdfName.TYPE)) && PdfName.WIDGET.equals(dict.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)) &&
            PdfName.SIG.equals(dict.getAsName(PdfName.FT)));
}
```

It works from objects i've tested it, but now i don't know if this covers all the pdf signature objects.

I need help to knowing, what is the pattern of signature objects in PDFs?

Comment: Please clarify which kinds of signature you want to remove. First of all it looks like you want to remove _digital signatures_, not simple electronic ones consisting just of e.g. an image of an ink signature. But there are different kinds of digital signatures, some kinds are specified as _interoperable signatures_ in the PDF specification but the spec also allows for other, custom kinds. Thus, which do you want to remove?

Comment: That being asked, please be aware that the **Type** *Sig* and the **Type** *Annot* are optional. Furthermore, **FT** *Sig* and **Subtype** *Widget* only are in the same dictionary if field dictionary and widget dictionary are merged - they indeed often are merged but not always. And _usage rights_ signatures are not necessarily indirect objects, so you won't necessarily find them directly by walking the cross references.

Comment: Any digital signature, i work with a large pdfs flow in my app, i need to remove all signatures before the user upload the pdf file in my app, because when he sign on my app, can have signature conflicts. This conflict will appears when i will create a new hash, above older broken signature, so i remove all the signatures before upload on my app. The second implementation will compose the remove signature method, with the first implementation. Only the first implementation   works well, but not for all cases.

Comment: Do you know if exists more than this two dictionary patterns for signatures?

Comment: If you create an app for pdf signing, you surely have read the relevant sections of the pdf specification, haven't you? That should make clear all about interoperable signature structures... *"because when he sign on my app, can have signature conflicts."* - this sounds like you either forgot to apply changes as incremental updates or you apply changes that aren't allowed to signed documents. Or you attempt to sign pdfs a previous signer did not intend to signed by others.

Comment: Regardless of everything you said, my goal is to remove all signatures from the document. My question is if my methods are meeting my objective?

Comment: *"Regardless of everything you said, my goal is to remove all signatures from the document. My question is if my methods are meeting my objective?"* - No, obviously not. How should your code recognize simple electronic signatures like images of ink signatures? And your methods don't even find all interoperative digital signatures, see my remarks on optional entries above.

Comment: But the first method can remove several tipes of signatures, the second can remove unusal signatures, it have works for me. 
Have you ever worked with PDF on a large scale or just read the documentation or ISO? Can you tell me where I can find these patterns? Do you have any publications or could you help me with this?